# JTextPane within a GridBagLayout do not behave the desired way

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane, gridbaglayout

I have encountered the following problem in my program. I have a JPanel with a GridBagLayout within a JScrollPanel. It should have the following behavior:

1. Scrolling should be only vertically possible.
2. In the JPanel rows are added dynamically. Those rows have two columns. Both columns should divide the space equally.
3. Each field (column/row) of this table is a JTextPane, because the text can be edited and can display HTML. If the text is too long, it will be wrapped with the effect, that the field's height grows.
4. When resizing the window, the columns resize too.

The problem is, when there is a long text:

- When using JTextPane without PreferredSize than the wrapping does not work and the columns are not divided equally. Setting Preferred size, the JTextPane cuts the text in the second line. JEditorPane also does not work.
- When using JTextArea with activated wrap, than it works! However, i can not display HTML. Furthermore the fourth point is not fulfilled. When extending the window, the field also resize. But when again making the window smaller, it doesn't resize back.

How can I get the desired behavior and avoid those problems? I already exhausted all possibilities I can think of.

Here is a picture of the desired behavior using `JTextPanes` (but without HTML):

[image: Here is a picture of the desired behavior using <code>JTextPanes</code> (but without HTML)]

Here is the wrong behavior using `JTextPanes`:

[image: Here is the wrong behavior using JTextPanes:]

And here a code for a SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class EditorTest extends JFrame {
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private JPanel jPanel2;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JTextPane jTextPane1;
    private JTextPane jTextPane2;

    public EditorTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        jPanel2 = new JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jTextPane2 = new JTextPane();
        jTextPane1 = new JTextPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        jPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        jPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        jTextPane2.setContentType("text/html"); 

        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 3, 3);
        jPanel1.add(jTextPane2, gridBagConstraints);

        jTextPane1.setContentType("text/html");
        jTextPane1.setText("This is a very long text that also sometimes is "
                + "<span style=\"color:blue\">blue</span> and so on and so on.");
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 3, 3);
        jPanel1.add(jTextPane1, gridBagConstraints);

        jPanel2.add(jPanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel2);

        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }                     

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new EditorTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }            
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

**UPDATE1**

To make the desired behavior more clear I created an other screenshot with a `JTextArea`, like in the first picture overhead. The TextPanes should be at the top and only as high as needed (i.e. the text). To illustrate this behavior, also changed the background of the text field.

[image]

Comment: You should specify the preferred and maximum size of the jtextpane. The width should be half of your jpanel, and the hight should be the default one. (ie. Super.getPreferredSize().height).

Comment: Dear @user1967800, thank you for your comment! Setting the `setMaximumSize()` does not have any effect. However, setting `getPreferredSize()` with the parameters you suggest, the width is displayed correctly, but the height fills the whole window. Maybe this comes very close! Do you have an other idea, how to adjust the height now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood me so here is a class to show you more clearly :

```
private class MyJTextPane extends JTextPane {
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(245,super.getPreferredSize().height);
    }
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }
}
```

You can use this class in your SSCCE to see how it behave.

This is just to give you an idea of how to use getMaximumSize and getPreferredSize to reach your goal. What you have to understand is that for a given width, the default getPreferredSize method returns the height needed to display the JTextPane content.

In your case, you just need to replace 245 by the final width you expect. You can use a function as well if the width depends on other elements.

Tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Dear @user1967800, thank you very much, this works perfectly! After reading your post, I also read further articles about preferredSize, maximumSize etc. and think, I understand it now much better. I have learnt a lot from you!

Answer (score 2):

I think I've coded what you wanted.

I had to set a preferred size for the JPanel inside the scroll pane.  The width can be whatever you want.  The height will have to be adjusted for the size of the JTextPanes.

Here's an image of the GUI.

[image: Editor Test]

And here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class EditorTest extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8019172274009058078L;

    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JTextPane jTextPane1;
    private JTextPane jTextPane2;

    public EditorTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jTextPane2 = new JTextPane();
        jTextPane1 = new JTextPane();

        setTitle("Editor Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        jScrollPane1
                .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        jScrollPane1
                .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        jTextPane2.setContentType("text/html");
        jTextPane2
                .setText("<html>This is a very long text that also sometimes is "
                        + "<span style=\"color:green\">green</span> and so on and so on.");

        jTextPane1.setContentType("text/html");
        jTextPane1
                .setText("<html>This is a very long text that also sometimes is "
                        + "<span style=\"color:blue\">blue</span> and so on and so on.");

        jPanel1.add(jTextPane1);
        jPanel1.add(jTextPane2);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel1);

        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new EditorTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @GilbertLeBlanc, thank you for your quick answer! I studied your answer closely and experimented with it. Unfortunately, I don't get the desired behavior. The `JTextPane` should be at the top and not higher than needed (i.e. the text), because other rows can be added dynamically. Furthermore if it is possible, I would like to use a GirdBagLayout for the JTextPanes. I am sorry if my question was not clear enough, I will update it once again! Do you think this is possible? I sincerely appreciate your help and efforts.

Comment: Dear @GilbertLeBlanc, I updated the question with an other screenshot. Thank you!